# (vba )add value in cell to vlookup outcome

Tags: excel, vba

Right now I have this code:

```
stockvalue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("In_bestelling").Range("G2").value, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Producten").Range("B1:D9000"), 2, False)
```

So this returns 5.
What I need to do is set the value of the cell that vlookup gets to the value it has now plus another value.

So in this case the other value is 10 and vlookup found 5 so it needs to putt 15 in the cell that says 5.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same value of the cell like this:

```
Dim stockvalue As Long
Dim ItemRow As Long

'wtih Application.Match we will find the row in column B that matches your item in G2
ItemRow = Application.Match(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("In_bestelling").Range("G2").Value, _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Producten").Range("B1:B9000"), 0)
'Here we will change the value of the cell where the item was found with it's value + stockvalue
stockvalue = 10 'change this for whatever you need to add
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Producten")
    .Cells(ItemRow, 4) = .Cells(ItemRow, 4) + stockvalue
End With
```

Comment: I need to change the cell that has been found by the vlookup.

So for example vlookup finds 5 and I want to add 10 tot that 5

Comment: You are getting a value, but you want to change the cell?

Comment: Vlookup finds the number 5 as the current stock. But I have ordered like 10 items of that product. So I want to add the 10 items to the 5 that are already in stock.

Comment: @klaas123 check my edit, `stockvalue` will hold now the value found + 10

Comment: It didnt change the value that was found by the vlookup. It didnt change anything at all.

Comment: That's what i was thinking... you want to find the cell holding your stock and then add 10 to it, like i told you before, right?

Comment: Yes I guess. Sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: ok @klaas123 now that we are on the same line, this code is what you need :)

Comment: Hi Thank you it works. Except I have a private sub in the sheet producten. When I loop trough the code with F8 and it wants to to jump to the end with it automaticly jumps to that code do you know why that is?

Comment: @klaas123 is your sub a `Worksheet_Change`event? If so, add `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the start of my code and turn it back on at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim wsIn As Worksheet, wsPro As Worksheet, rngFound
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim FoundValue As Long, ResultValue As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsIn = .Sheets("In_bestelling")
        Set wsPro = .Sheets("Producten")
    End With

    SearchString = wsIn.Range("G2").Value

    Set rngFound = wsPro.Range("B1:D9000").Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then

        With wsPro
            FoundValue = .Cells(rngFound.Row, rngFound.Column + 1).Value
            ResultValue = FoundValue + 10
            .Cells(rngFound.Row, rngFound.Column + 1) = ResultValue
        End With

    Else
        MsgBox "No Match!"
    End If

End Sub
```